# How does java run batch file in the background

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

How does java run a batch file in the background?

I have a batch file with the following content

```
@echo off

:start
start /b cmd /c example.exe -c config >nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

In fact, I run this code under the command line, it can run in the background, but it seems that the "execution" of the java call will hang on the console on the idea, I am a java novice and I don't know the principle.

java code:

```java
package com.example;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        System.out.println("Started.");
        String script_path = "";
        boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().startsWith("windows");
        System.out.println(isWindows);
        if (isWindows) {
            System.out.println("it's Windows");
            script_path = "c:/users/test-running/desktop/example.bat";
            CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("cmd");
            cmdLine.addArgument(script_path);
            cmdLine.addArgument("start").addArgument("server");
            DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
            executor.execute(cmdLine);
            System.out.println("Finished.");

        } else {
            System.out.println("it's Linux");
            script_path = "/Users/seth/Downloads/example.sh";
            CommandLine cmdLine = new CommandLine("/bin/bash");
            cmdLine.addArgument(script_path);
            cmdLine.addArgument("start").addArgument("server");
            DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
            executor.execute(cmdLine);
            System.out.println("Finished.");
        }
    }
}
```

So does anyone know what java is doing? Or is the syntax of the batch file wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with just ```@start "" "example.exe" -c config >nul 2>&1``` as your entire batch file content?

Comment: I supppose I should also question why you're sending all output to the NUL davice, but have code which 'prints' output?

Comment: @Compo that is example,  i tried output > example.log  no change